# Why do we pass callback functions as parameters if we can just call them within the body of the higher order function?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

Suppose we have a function `foo` as follows:

```
function foo(){
    alert("Hello, world!");
}
```

If I want to call `foo` from `bar`, why do we have to pass it as a callback?

```
function bar(callback){
    callback();
}

bar(foo);
```

If all we can do is just:

```
function bar(){
    foo();
}

bar();
```

Comment: You don't have to pass it as a callback unless your code requires it.

Comment: The point is that we can now call `bar` with *any* function, not just `foo`. Consider `bar(function() { console.log("Goodbye, world!"); })` - not possible if `bar` always calls `foo` only.

Answer (score 1):

Because we can pass any function we want to `bar`, so long as it matches the specified function signature.  Your way, we have to know the name of the `foo` function ahead of time, when we write `bar`.

The reason this is important is that it decreases [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)).